# LuaBridge assertion error

Tags: c++, lua, luabridge

I've been going through some tutorials around luabridge for accessing c++ from lua but I've hit a problem I can't seem to find an answer to by searching google.

I've setup a sample program to run the script and access lua from c++, which works fine. But when I try to register a function in the global namespace it complains during runtime - compiling just fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "../LuaBridge/LuaBridge.h"

using namespace luabridge;

void printMessage(const std::string& s) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();

    getGlobalNamespace(L).addFunction("printMessage", printMessage);

    luaL_dofile(L, "script.lua");
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    LuaRef s = getGlobal(L, "testString");
    LuaRef n = getGlobal(L, "number");
    std::string luaString = s.cast<std::string>();
    int answer = n.cast<int>();
    std::cout << luaString << std::endl;
    std::cout << "And here's our number:" << answer << std::endl;
}
```

So, this code *with* the addFunction call gives me this error

```
Lua: /home/linuxxon/Programming/kingdoms-online/Script/Lua/../LuaBridge/detail/Namespace.h:1080: luabridge::Namespace& luabridge::Namespace::addFunction(const char*, FP) [with FP = void (*)(const std::basic_string<char>&)]: Assertion `(lua_type(L, (-1)) == 5)' failed.
```

Withouth the addFunction call I get what is expected of the script.

Is there perhaps something obvious that I have missed, since I haven't found anything like it?

I would greatly appreciate all help!

Comment: Can you run it in a debugger and provide a full backtrace?

Comment: Could this be what you want? http://pastebin.com/eEbJWQ5n

Comment: What's in `script.lua`?

Comment: @Linuxxon: There is no need to edit your question title to say its solved. Instead, mark one of the answers as accepted. It is perfectly OK to accept your own answers, BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the

```
luaL_openlibs(L);
```

was after the script had been run. The problem was in the tutorial I was following, I encountered the same thing before in the beginning of my tries with lua.

It all works perfectly by calling it after creating the new lua state.

Comment: If you do not want to load all libs just call `luaL_requiref(state, "_G", &luaopen_base, 1); lua_pop(state, 1);` That is required module you have to load. Check the source of luaL_openlibs if you want to suppress opening certain modules.